# don't know [sudo] password for ec2-user

Tags: amazon-web-services, passwords

hi I just connected a ec2 instance(p3.2xlarge) by using putty right after I got the instance.

The problem is I tried a sudo command but I'm asked a sudo passwod for ec2-user
which I think I did not make.

how can I get to know my ec2-user password or reset it ?

Comment: The normal "Amazon Linux 2" should not ask for a sudo password, which suggests that you launched from a non-standard AMI. Which AMI did you use when launching the instance?